# SharePoint Wikipage

Tags: office-365, wiki-pages, image-display

I'm trying create wiki page in SharePoint but facing a problem with image.Could someone help me how to insert image below the text or any desire place with adjusted length and height.

Thanks in Advance

P.S.Is it possible to make image clickable or expand when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

**Modern pages**

you'd click on one of the "+"-Signs and select `Image`to insert.

[image: Modern page]

**Classic pages**

If you're using classic (and you do, if you really have a wiki-page) you place the cursor where the image should be inserted, the go to ribbon -> insert -> picture

[image]

**Click a picture**

You can not "enlarge" a picture in SharePoint-Standard. However, since the picture resides on the SharePoint, you could add a hyperlink to the source like this:

- Upload the picture to SharePoint
- Edit the Wiki-Page
- Ribbon -> insert -> Link -> from SharePoint
- Chose the picture. Now the name of the picture is a hyperlink to the picture.
- place the cursor in the middle of the name
- Ribbon -> insert -> picture -> from SharePoint
- Chose the picture again.
- remove the name-characters that surround from the wiki-page.

Now you have a clickable picture.

**If you do not have a place to store the pictures**

Create one!

- gear-symbol -> add an app
  [image]
- "picture library"
  [image]
- add images there...
  [image]

Comment: where to put image to find link in sharePoint

Comment: I have updated the answer. I suggest you get a bit more familiar with SharePoint. I.e. have a look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-SharePoint-909ec2f0-05c8-4e92-8ad3-3f8b0b6cf261